# create a numpy structured array from a list of strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a python utility to get data from the Tycho 2 star catalogue.  One of the functions I am working on queries the catalogue and returns all the information for a given star id (or set of star ids).

I'm currently doing this by looping through the lines of the catalogue file and then attempting to parse the line into a numpy structured array if it was queried. (note if there is a better way to do this you can let me know even though this is not what this question is about --  I'm doing it this way because the catalogue is too big to load all of it into memory at one time)

Anyway, once I have identified a record that I want to keep I've run into a problem... I can't figure out how to parse it into a structured array.

For instance, say the record I want to keep is:

```
record = '0002 00038 1| |  3.64121230|  1.08701186|   14.1|  -23.0| 69| 82| 1.8| 1.9|1968.56|1957.30| 3|1.0|3.0|0.9|3.0|12.444|0.213|11.907|0.189|999| |         |  3.64117944|  1.08706861|1.83|1.73| 81.0|104.7| | 0.0'
```

Now,  I am trying to parse this into a numpy structured array with dtype:

```
        dform = [('starid', [('TYC1', int), ('TYC2', int), ('TYC3', int)]),
             ('pflag', str),
             ('starBearing', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('properMotion', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('uncertainty', [('rightAscension', int), ('declination', int), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('meanEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('numPos', int),
             ('fitGoodness', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('magnitude', [('BT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)]), ('VT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)])]),
             ('starProximity', int),
             ('tycho1flag', str),
             ('hipparcosNumber', str),
             ('observedPos', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedError', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('solutionType', str),
             ('correlation', float)]
```

This seems like it should be a fairly simple thing to do but everything I try breaks...

I've tried:

```
np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(record.encode()),dtype=dform,delimiter=(' ','|'))
np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(record.encode()),dtype=dform,delimiter=(' ','|'),missing_values=' ',filling_values=None)
```

both of which gives me

```
{TypeError}cannot perform accumulate with flexible type
```

which makes no sense since it shouldn't be doing any accumulation.

I've also tried

```
np.array(re.split('\|| ',record),dtype=dform)
```

which complains

```
{TypeError}a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and another variant

```
np.array([x.encode() for x in re.split('\|| ',record)],dtype=dform)
```

which doesn't throw an error but also certainly doesn't return the correct results:

```
[ ((842018864, 0, 0), '', (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0, 0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), 0, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), ((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)), 0, '', '', (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), '', 0.0)...
```

So how can I do this?  I think the genfromtxt option is the way to go (especially since there may be missing data occasionally) but I don't understand why it isn't working.  Is this something that I'm just going to have to write a parser for on my own?

Comment: Hmm...your `record` has 32 fields, but `dform` only seems to have `17`. How is that? I could imagine it to work otherwise with `np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(record.encode()),dtype=dform,delimiter='|')`, but anyway it seems ambiguous now.

Comment: since there isn't enough for me to recreate the problem, try switching your `str` to `np.str_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this answer is long and rambling, but that's what it took to figure out what is going on.  The complexity of the dtype in particular was hidden by its length.

---

I get the `TypeError: cannot perform accumulate with flexible type` error when I try your list for `delimiter`.  The details show the error occurs in `LineSplitter`.  Without getting into details, the delimiter should be one character (or the default 'whitespace').

From the `genfromtxt` docs:

> delimiter : str, int, or sequence, optional
>           The string used to separate values.  By default, any consecutive
>           whitespaces act as delimiter.  An integer or sequence of integers
>           can also be provided as width(s) of each field.

The `genfromtxt` splitter is a little more powerful than the string `.split` that `loadtxt` uses, but not as general as the `re` splitter.

As for the `{TypeError}a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, you specify, for a couple of the fields, dtype `'str'`.  That's byte string, where as your `record` is unicode string (in Py3).  But you've already realized that with `BytesIO(record.encode())`.

I like to test `genfromtxt` cases with:

```
record = b'....'
np.genfromtxt([record], ....)
```

Or better yet

```
records = b"""one line
tow line
three line
"""
np.genfromtxt(records.splitlines(), ....)
```

If I let `genfromtxt` deduce field types, and just use the one delimiter, I get 32 fields:

```
In [19]: A=np.genfromtxt([record],dtype=None,delimiter='|')
In [20]: len(A.dtype)
Out[20]: 32
In [21]: A
Out[21]: 
array((b'0002 00038 1', False, 3.6412123, 1.08701186, 14.1, -23.0, 69, 82, 1.8, 1.9, 1968.56, 1957.3, 3, 1.0, 3.0, 0.9, 3.0, 12.444, 0.213, 11.907, 0.189, 999, False, False, 3.64117944, 1.08706861, 1.83, 1.73, 81.0, 104.7, False, 0.0), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S12'), ('f1', '?'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ... ('f26', '<f8'), ('f27', '<f8'), ('f28', '<f8'), ('f29', '<f8'), ('f30', '?'), ('f31', '<f8')])
```

When we get the whole byte and delimiter issues worked out

```
np.array([x for x in re.split(b'\|| ',record)],dtype=dform)
```

does run.  I now see that your dform is complex, with nested compound fields.

But to define a structured array, you to give it a list of records, e.g.

```
np.array([(record1...), (record2...), ....], dtype([(field1),(field2 ),...]))
```

Here you are trying to create one record.  I could wrap your list in a tuple, but then I get a mismatch between that length and `dform` length, 66 v 17.  If you count all the subfields `dform` might take 66 values, but we can't just do that with one tuple.

I've never tried to create an array from such a complex `dtype`, so I'm fishing around for ways to make it work.

```
In [41]: np.zeros((1,),dform)
Out[41]: 
array([ ((0, 0, 0), '', (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0, 0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), 0, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), ((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)), 0, '', '', (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), '', 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('starid', [('TYC1', '<i4'), ('TYC2', '<i4'), ('TYC3', '<i4')]), ('pflag', '<U'), ('starBearing', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]), ('properMotion', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]), ('uncertainty', [('rightAscension', '<i4'), ('declination', '<i4'), ('pmRA', '<f8'), ('pmDc', '<f8')]), ('meanEpoch', ....('solutionType', '<U'), ('correlation', '<f8')])

In [64]: for name in A.dtype.names:
    print(A[name].dtype)
   ....:     
[('TYC1', '<i4'), ('TYC2', '<i4'), ('TYC3', '<i4')]
<U1
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
[('rightAscension', '<i4'), ('declination', '<i4'), ('pmRA', '<f8'), ('pmDc', '<f8')]
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
int32
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8'), ('pmRA', '<f8'), ('pmDc', '<f8')]
[('BT', [('mag', '<f8'), ('err', '<f8')]), ('VT', [('mag', '<f8'), ('err', '<f8')])]
int32
<U1
<U1
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
[('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]
<U1
float64
```

I count 34 primitive dtype fields.  Most are 'scalar', some 2-4 terms, one has a further level of nesting.

If I replace the first 2 spliting spaces with `|`, `record.split(b'|')` gives me 34 strings.

Lets try that in `genfromtxt`:

```
In [79]: np.genfromtxt([record],delimiter='|',dtype=dform)
Out[79]: 
array(((2, 38, 1), '', (3.6412123, 1.08701186), (14.1, -23.0), 
   (69, 82, 1.8, 1.9), (1968.56, 1957.3), 3, (1.0, 3.0, 0.9, 3.0),
   ((12.444, 0.213), (11.907, 0.189)), 999, '', '', 
   (3.64117944, 1.08706861), (1.83, 1.73), (81.0, 104.7), '', 0.0), 
      dtype=[('starid', [('TYC1', '<i4'), ('TYC2', '<i4'), ('TYC3', '<i4')]), 
 ('pflag', '<U'), 
 ('starBearing', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]),  
 ('properMotion', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]),
 ('uncertainty', [('rightAscension', '<i4'), ('declination', '<i4'), ('pmRA', '<f8'), ('pmDc', '<f8')]), 
 ('meanEpoch', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]),   
 ('numPos', '<i4'), 
 ('fitGoodness', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8'), ('pmRA', '<f8'), ('pmDc', '<f8')]), 
 ('magnitude', [('BT', [('mag', '<f8'), ('err', '<f8')]), ('VT', [('mag', '<f8'), ('err', '<f8')])]), 
 ('starProximity', '<i4'), ('tycho1flag', '<U'), ('hipparcosNumber', '<U'), 
 ('observedPos', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]),
 ('observedEpoch', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]), 
 ('observedError', [('rightAscension', '<f8'), ('declination', '<f8')]), ('solutionType', '<U'), ('correlation', '<f8')])
```

That almost looks reasonable.  `genfromtxt` can actually split the values up among the compound fields.  That's more that what I'd want to try with `np.array()`.

So if you get the delimiters and byte/unicode worked out, `genfromtxt` can handle this mess.

Comment: Thanks for the time in writing this out.  It was really helpful.  The problem was (as you stated) that genfromtxt can only handle a single delimiter.  Things seem to be mostly working now except for another issue which I will ask in another question.