# How to do ordered comparisons like `<` on structured numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) that has some `dtype` tuple, it seems you can sort and do `==` but not operations like `<` for lexicographic ordering.

For example, say I have an array of tuples:

```
A = np.array([(3, 2),
              (1, 8),
              (5, 1),
              (3, 1),
              (4, 7)],
             dtype='i8,i8')
```

Calling `sort` works as expected, lexicographic ordering of the tuples:

```
>>> np.sort(A)
array([(3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 7), (5, 1), (6, 8)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

And it's even possible to do vectorized equality/inequality comparison:

```
>>> x = A[3]
>>> A != x
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

But trying to do ordered comparisons like `<`, `<=`, `>=` raises

```
>>> A < x
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The best solution I have so far is to "manually" implement lexicographic ordering columnwise, but this technique doesn't extend easily to higher tuple dimensions and just feels like the "wrong way":

```
>>> (A['f0'] < x[0]) | ((A['f0'] == x[0]) & (A['f1'] < x[1]))
array([False,  True, False, False, False])
```

(My **actual problem** is that I have a very large array of such tuples and I need to extract all the tuples that come before a certain one lexicographically. Sorting works but takes too long.)

Comment: A [previous question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421249/comparing-numpy-structured-arrays) might be of some help.

Comment: Using structured arrays when all fields have the same dtype is purely an indexing convenience.  When dtypes differ, especially some are strings (as when loaded from a csv), comparisons, and cross field math, is not well defined and not implemented. You are lucky to get sorting and equality.

Comment: @sj95126 thanks for the pointer but it doesn't answer my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand the issue but doesn't sorting somehow *require* comparisons? It seems strange that the more complicated operation is possible but the simpler one isn't.

Comment: `structured array` sort is lexicographic. You can specify which fields to use and their priority.

Comment: @hpaulj (As I wrote) I know I can sort but that is far too slow for the size of array in my application.